# Disable Long Press of ListView with custom renderer

Tags: android, android-listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm attempting to disable the "long press" animation that seems to come by default on Android devices using Xamarin Forms. I have a custom renderer written (that properly works, I can change the background, etc.. and the changes are resounded in the listview).  Here is the core of my renderer:

```
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<ListView> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);
        if (Control != null) {
            Control.LongClickable = false;
        }
    }
```

I have also tried `Control.SetOnLongClickListener (null)`. Neither of the above controls seem to affect the long press behavior of the listview. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: 1. What resource do you use for items? 2. By animation do you mean selection animation?

Comment: I am using an ObservableCollection. Yup, on long press there is a separate animation from the regular selection highlighting that I am trying to disable.

Comment: By resource I mean layout you are using.

Comment: Whoops, sorry! My ListView is inside a StackLayout.

Comment: Have you found a solution yet?

Comment: Unfortunately no longer pursuing a solution :(